# How to refer same DataTable across different features in cucumber-jvm?

Tags: cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm, gherkin

In one of step definitions I have created a function say “someFunction” that takes a  DataTable, which has been defined in my feature file Feature1.

```
Feature1.feature
Given: User enters the following data
Varibale1|Variable2|Variable3
Value1|Value2|Value3

StpeDef.java
@Given(“^User enters the following data$”)
public void someFunction(DataTable input){
}
```

Now in another feature file “Feature2.feature”, one of my scenario needs to use same step i.e. call someFunction. I know I can use the same step definition but does that mean that I would have to redefine same DataTable input in Feature2 file.
 If not, how would I do it? 
Please note that I understand the Backgound keyword and its use, but if I say I need to keep these scenarios in different feature files, how should this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to duplicate the common background. Since duplication is unwanted, you should consider giving a name/title to the resulting state that is represented by that common background and create a single given step that can be re-used. Something like "Given: the user has entered valid contact data" or "Given: the shopping cart has 3 items" (where any 3 will do).

Comment: Could you please help me understand with example or resulting feature files?